# Upload input don't work when AJAX is invoked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, node.js

Uploading is working when JQuery function -AJAX- is not called, when I call JQuery then sending data work but uploading don't

```
// This id for AJAX
<div id="addAdv">

  //This form for JavaScript.onclick and for upload request
  <form id="formAddAdv" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload">

   <fieldset>

    //Upload input with name
    <input type="file" name="upl"/>

    //Some data to send using AJAX
    <label for="inputAdvName">Title</label>
    <input id="inputAdvName" type="text" /><br/>
    <label for="inputStatus">Description</label>
    <textarea id="inputStatus"></textarea><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
  </fieldset>
 </form>
</div>

$('#formAddAdv').submit(addAdv);
```

**AJAX:**

```
function addAdv(event) {
.....
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: newUser,
    url: '/addadv',
    dataType: 'JSON'
}).done(function( response )...}
```

**Node.JS routes:**

```
router.post('/upload', upload, function (req, res, next) {

    console.log(req.file);
    res.status(204).end();

});

router.post('/addadv', function(req, res) {

    Feed.collection.insert(req.body, function(err, result){
        res.send(
            (err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: err }
        );
    });
});
```

Each function works fine alone, unless I try to merge upload input inside AJAX form.

Comment: You should show your jQuery function

Comment: _`//Some data to send using AJAX`_ AJAX does not appear at Question ?

Comment: Edited. please review.